# Hide "Your name" field in comment form from everyone except admin

Tags: comments

What I want to achieve is to hide the "Your name" field in *comment form* from all anonymous and authenticated users but visible to users with the admin role.

I was able to use CSS to hide the field, but it also hides from admin.

Please is there a way to selectively hide the field to anonymous and authenticated users but not to administrators?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function YOURMODULE_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;

  if ($user->uid != 1) {
    unset($form['author']['name']);
  }

}
```

Another way is, if your theme has a comment.tpl.php file, putting a condition to restrict authenticated and anonymous user.

```
<?php print $author; ?>
```

To limit this to a particular content type, you can create a separate comment template file for that content type.

Comment: Thank you. I used the first solution and it works! Please, is there a line to add to the code to limit this to a particular content type e.g article content type?

Answer (score 4):

If you have more than one users having *administrator* role then you may use this snippet. Place this piece of code at the bottom of `template.php` of your current theme.

Note: Replace *YOUR_THEMENAME* with the name of your current theme and *YOUR_FORM_ID_HERE* with *id* of your form.

```
function YOUR_THEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch($form_id){
    case 'YOUR_FORM_ID_HERE':
      global $user;
      if (!in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
          unset($form['author']['name']);
      }

    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: @seyi this solution is better as it will work for all the admin users, not just only one user with uid 1.